# How to return string from list if result of contains function is true in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to create a column with the value in a list that the function contains locate, like following example:

```py
data= [
  (1,"john_trader@gmail.com"),
  (2, "lucas turism llc"),
  (3,"maryinvestor@gmail.com")
]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id",'content'))

words = ["trader", "turism", "investor"]
conditions = " or ".join([f"content like '%{word}%'" for word in words])

df2 = df.withColumn('contains', F.expr(conditions))

+---+------------------------+--------+
|id |content                 |contains|
+---+------------------------+--------+
|1  |john_trader@gmail.com   |true    |
|2  |lucas turism llc        |true    |
|3  |maryinvestor@gmail.com  |true    |
|4  |peter.anderson@gmail.com|false   |
+---+------------------------+--------+
```

The desire output:

```py
+---+------------------------+--------+--------+
|id |content                 |contains|match   |
+---+------------------------+--------+--------+
|1  |john_trader@gmail.com   |true    |trader  |
|2  |lucas turism llc        |true    |turism  |
|3  |maryinvestor@gmail.com  |true    |investor|
|4  |peter.anderson@gmail.com|false   |null    |
+---+------------------------+--------+--------+
```

I found this code in other answer, but this doesn't work for words together, only to space words, like 'turism' example, and I don't know to adapt to my case. :(

```py
word_list_arr = F.array(*[F.lit(w) for w in words])

df2 = df2.withColumn(
    "match",
    F.array_join(F.array_intersect(F.split("content", " "), word_list_arr), " ")
).withColumn("match", F.expr("nullif(match, '')"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use contains.

```
 (df.withColumn('match', explode(F.array(*[F.lit(w) for w in words])))#Insert words, a word per row
 .withColumn('contains', col("content").contains(col("match")))#Check if word in column match exists in column content
 .where(col('contains')=='true')#Filter out only those that ar etrue
).show(truncate=False)
```